# React state is empty when submitting the form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not new to react, but for some weird reason, I have came across a quick example I was testing, and I noticed that the state is coming out empty string. as if it were not updating.
I am using react 18.1, and here is a **stack blitz** instance to see the code live (a sandbox), [click me](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mbk7wj?file=src/App.js).

Full code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [qr, setQr] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('The submitted QR code is: ', qr);
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setQr(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input onChange={handleChange} value={qr} />
    </form>
  );
}
```

can anyone please explain why the state is not ready when submitting the form? and how do you work this out?

I was actually working on a larger project, and when I came across this *bug*, I decided to demonstrate this in a smaller quick example in a sandbox.

Thanks yous

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is in your alert. The value is actually being updated on change, but alert only takes a single argument and you're passing it two.

Instead, you can concatenate the string like so to produce the desired result:

```js
alert(`The submitted QR code is: ${qr}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

alert should return a string, so you should give it a string:

```
 alert('The submitted QR code is: ', qr);
 // the ',' is not for concat

 // use instead:
 alert(`The submitted QR code is: ${qr}`);
 //or
 alert('The submitted QR code is: ' + qr);
```